# How to properly check a List for a match when no match is expected?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, list, exception

New to Python idioms and syntax.  I have a Datastore StringListProperty that holds user keys.  For most entities this property will have 0-10 keys, sometimes many more.  I need to check the property for a key, most often there will be no match.

```
if entity.string_list.index(user_key) is not None:
  # ....
```

This is throwing an error when there's no matching key.  I can catch the exception, but I suspect I am not properly understanding how to check for matches in a List.

Comment: If you're storing keys, you should use a db.ListProperty(db.Key), not a StringListProperty. 'in' works just as well for those, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> strings = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> 'def' in strings
True
>>> 'foo' in strings
False
```

Comment: I love how it's so intuitive. Python <3

Answer (score 5):

First off, if you're going to do a lot of searching you should use a set or a dictionary instead of a list unless you need to maintain order.  Lookup on lists is O(n) and I know that tuples/dictionaries are much better.  I believe constant time lookup.

Second, you're right about try/catch, you should use that if you expect that most of the time there *WILL* be a match.

Third, I think you're looking for,

```
if user_key in entity.string_list:
    idx = entity.string_list.index(user_key)
```

EDIT: here are two links that shed some light on runtime guarantees.  Very good stuff to know offhand when coding to keep your runtime down automatically
http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
http://bayes.colorado.edu/PythonIdioms.html

EDIT2: added method using dictionaries.

```
## pre-initialize a dictionary
lookupdict = dict((val, i) for i, val in enumerate(entity.string_list))

# loop over user_key
    idx = lookupdict.get(user_key, None)
    if idx is None:
        continue

    ## do something with idx
```

Comment: The reason this is in a List is because Google advises using ListProperties instead of ReferenceProperties for storing keys in many to many relationships.  It's more processing to handle the ReferenceProperty.  I assume their answer accounted for the Python side of things.  ??

Comment: A set is not a reference property that I can see from their documentation.  I think they are just saying that things that are ListProperties are going to be given back to you (from their internal datastore) as a list.  It doesn't exclude you from using sets.  Consider the running time difference.  If you only use lists and you do `k` lookups, then worst-case you're looking at `k*n` lookups.  By using a dictionary you would have an initial cost of `n` but then lookups after that are only `1` so you're looking at `k+n`.  Made some edits to show you how to use a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
if user_key in entity.string_list:
    # ...
```